# Several figures with one caption in a two-column Latex document

Tags: latex, position, figure, caption

What I want is
[image: Screen]

What I do is:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\makebox[\paperwidth]
{
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth]{1.jpeg}
\label{1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth]{2.jpeg}
\label{2}
\end{subfigure}
} \par
\makebox[\paperwidth]
{
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth]{3.jpeg}
\label{3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth]{4.jpeg}
\label{4}
\end{subfigure}
} \par
\caption{\label{pic-map} ...}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

Box appeared to be the only solution to place these four images in two columns, but what happens now is that pictures are shifted and overlapping the second column and the caption remains in the first column:
[image: Pictures are shifted and overlapping the second column and the caption remains in the first column]

What could I do in such a situation?

Comment: use `\begin{figure*}` for full-width figures in multi-column documents. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document

Comment: Thanks! That worked!
Although I have tried it before :-\ Maybe the issue was in using

    \begin{figure*}[H]
before

Answer (score -1):

```latex
\begin{figure*}[]% [hpbt] what you need
    \centering
     \subfigure[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{gen_1_1.png}
        \label{fig:gull}}
     \subfigure[]{%{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{gen_1_1.png}
        \label{fig:tiger}}
         \subfigure[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{gen_1_1.png}}
        \label{fig:gull}}
     \subfigure[]{%{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{gen_1_1.png}
        \label{fig:tiger}}
    \caption{Pictures}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext
```

Will return as the four intended figures and text.

[image]